# Which is better for running recommendations on a Hadoop cluster, Apache Mahout or using R with Hadoop (via hadoop streaming/RHIPE/RHadoop etc)?

Tags: r, hadoop, mahout, hadoop-streaming, rhadoop

I am new to Big-data and looking for a good platform **to perform recommendations,clustering and classification**. I understand Mahout has many algorithms to do this. Also R itself being a very good analytical tool is more than helpful for achieving this. Since I'm looking into bigdata I'll be using R+hadoop (via streaming/RHIPE/RHadoop etc.) if I decide to take this path. 
I'm seeking a comparison with respect to performance, scalability, ease of use, maturity etc considering that the difference in complexity of the language used (Java in mahout and R ) is not a factor to me at this point.

Comment: If you want to use Hadoop, what is going to stop you from using Mahout as it runs on Hadoop? did you find any drawbacks?

Answer (score 2):

Mahout integrates many algorithms, and it deals with three questions
(1) Recommendation (Collaborative filtering algorithm)
(2) Clustering
(3) Classification

R is just for statistic, so if you want to do these three tasks above, Mahout is a great tool.

BTW, Mahout is a Maven project, so you need to install Maven.